# TypeError: this.responsearray.find is not a function angular

Tags: angular, angular8

I am getting the below error when trying to countryName in the response array.

```
TypeError: this.responsearray.find is not a function
```

Here is my ts code

this is what I declared

```
 responsearray: any;
      editCountry(row){
        let founditem = this.responsearray.find(item => item.countryName==row);
        console.log(founditem)
        if(founditem !== undefined){
        const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(popupcomponent, {
          width: '800px',
          panelClass: 'custom-modalbox',
          disableClose: true,
          data: {pageValue:founditem}   
        });

        dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
          console.log('The dialog was closed');
          if (!result) {
            this.loadData();
          }
        });
      }
      }
```

Here is my Interface

```
export interface assumption {
countryID: number;    
CountryName: string;
UserId: number;
UserName: string;
JoiningDate: String;
BirthDate: String;
OverallLength:number;}
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

responsearray should be **Array**  and please **initiate** it.

Answer (score 1):

Typescript is finicky with types. You need to initialize `responsearray` variable as an array to use `find()` method on it.

```js
responsearray = [];
```

Answer (score 1):

Missing type for the array

```
class App {
  private responsearray: assumption[] = [];
  editCountry(row) {
    let founditem = this.responsearray.find(item => item.CountryName == row);
    if (founditem !== undefined) {
      const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(popupcomponent, {
        width: "800px",
        panelClass: "custom-modalbox",
        disableClose: true,
        data: { pageValue: founditem }
      });

      dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
        console.log("The dialog was closed");
        if (!result) {
          this.loadData();
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
export interface assumption {
  countryID: number;
  CountryName: string;
  UserId: number;
  UserName: string;
  JoiningDate: String;
  BirthDate: String;
  OverallLength: number;
}
```